# Looping result from select statement throws error

Tags: php, sqlsrv

```
    <?php
include 'config.php';
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn1, "SELECT * FROM dnmembership.[dbo].DNAuth a JOIN dnworld.[dbo] Characters b ON a.CharacterID = b.CharacterID where a.CertifyingStep = 2");

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $row['CharacterName']. '<br/>';
}
?>
```

This code gets met the folllowing error code:
Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\usersonline.php on line 5

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a period (`.`) between `[dbo]` and `Characters`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dnmembership.[dbo].DNAuth a 
JOIN   dnworld.[dbo].Characters b ON a.CharacterID = b.CharacterID 
------------- Here -^
WHERE  a.CertifyingStep = 2
```